# Second argument of fopen

Tags: c, fopen, arguments

OK, so I'm writing a game, and in this game, there's an interactive settings menu. What I want to do is write to the file if it doesn't exist, read from the file if it does, apply settings specified in the file, and overwrite it with new settings from the user, if the user chooses to change the settings. So it would go something like this (psuedo-code):

```
if (file does not exist)
    write_defaults
open settings
read from file
apply settings specified in file
while (user is changing settings)
    if (user is done) break
write new settings to file
apply new settings
```

Now what would I use for fopen's second argument? I've tried both "r+" and "w+" but I've had problems with both.

Answer (score 2):

I would open as `"w"` for the write operations, and reopen as `"r"` for the read operations, unless you're doing some sort of random-access simultaneous read/write.

As @stefan has mentioned in a comment below, you would want `"rb"` or `"wb"` if you are manipulating raw binary data rather than text.

Comment: Yes, this is the right way you shouldnt keep the file open more than needed with fopen. Open - Read - Close. Open - Write - Close. Also you might need to add b, depending what data you are writing.

Answer (score 0):

Using `"r+"` is correct for the first attempt; if it fails because the file does not exist, then try again with `"w+"`.  This gives you a file open for update, but doesn't clobber a file if it already exists.

However, this is sub-optimal in the sense that there's a TOCTOU (time of check, time of use) vulnerability - if the file is created between the failed open with `"r+"` and the successful open with `"w+"`, the information in the file will be lost.

If you have access to POSIX functions, you can use `open()` instead of `fopen()` to do the job correctly in one atomic attempt, followed by `fdopen()` to convert the file descriptor into a file stream.

```
FILE *carefully_open(const char *file)
{
    int fd = open(file, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0644);
    FILE *fp = 0;

    if (fd >= 0)
        fp = fdopen(fd, "r+");
    if (fd >= 0 && fp == 0)
        close(fd);
    return fp;
}
```

The one downside to this is that it will create a file through a broken symlink.  You can avoid that with the `O_EXCL` flag, but then the open will fail if the file does exist.  You end up making two calls to `open()` after all, one with just `O_RDRW` and the second with `O_RDRW | O_CREAT | O_EXCL` to be safe against following broken symlnks.

(What is a broken symlink?  If there is no file `pqr` in the current directory, `ln -s ./pqr xyz` means that `xyz` is a broken symlink that will be 'fixed' by creating file 'pqr' with the `open()` call shown.)

What problems did you have?

Answer (score 0):

Just open the file with "r+". Check the returned pointer, if the pointer is not NULL, read settings from file. Then write to file.